# Regex match one of two words

Tags: regex, forms, validation

I have an input that can have only 2 values `apple` or `banana`. What regular expression can I use to ensure that either of the two words was submitted?

Comment: In what language/environment is this regex being implemented? Regex seems like unnecessary overhead in many situations.

Answer (score 775, accepted):

This will do:

```
/^(apple|banana)$/
```

to *exclude* from captured strings (e.g. `$1`,`$2`):

```
(?:apple|banana)
```

Or, if you use a standalone pattern:

```
apple|banana
```

Comment: For some, using this as a non-capturing group will be useful. Using `(?:apple|banna)` will match either, but will not add them to the list of captured strings (eg `$1`, `$2`.. `$N`).

Comment: Hi quick question,

what should I do if I do not want applebanana to match?

Comment: The regex above matches apple and banana, but does not match applebanana.

Comment: Do not confuse round brackets that are used here with square brackets for a character class.

Comment: What does _captured strings_ mean?

Comment: When used with grep in a bash shell, you should escape the `|`
example: `cat file | grep 'apple\|banana'`

Comment: And if you need whole words, use word boundaries instead of `^` and `$` anchors, e.g. `\b(?:apple|banana)\b`

Comment: Why it doesn't matches `apple banana` please check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/b14d228689c1).

Answer (score 143):

There are different regex engines but I think most of them will work with this:

```
apple|banana
```

Comment: If you plan to put more in your regex, you'll need to put parentheses around your words, like this: `(apple|banana)`.

Comment: but how to make it case insensitive?

Comment: That's set with the `re.IGNORECASE` flag. E.g.: `re.compile("(apple|banana)", re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @BrianJ Why add parentheses? It works even without them, check this [regex demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/182ba34e74dd).

Comment: The parentheses is for if the expression is longer than just "apple or banana". So if you had `shopping list (apple|banana)` as your regex you could match `shopping list apple` and you could match `shopping list banana`.