# Identifying either of two different substrings in the filename using Regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, gnu-findutils

When I run my script, I specify a pattern I'm looking for in the files located in the source directory. Pattern can be located anywhere in the filename.

When I do:

```
sh packageScript.sh -p ".*TOM.*
```

The script works as desired and all the files with "TOM" in the name are packaged up.

But if I want the script to package up files with "TOM" or "*JER*" in the name, the script fails. I tried each of the following:

```
sh packageScript.sh -p ".*TOM.*||.*_JER_.*"
sh packageScript.sh -p ".*TOM.*|.*_JER_.*"
```

The for loop that iterates over the files in my script:

```
for file in $(find -regex "$PATTERN" -type f);
do 
 //things get done here
done
```

(I assign the value of the -p flag to $PATTERN in a "while getopts" at the top of my script)

Sample file names:

```
M_V_CHUCK_TOM_20180105.txt
M_V_CHUCK_TOM_20170105.txt
M_V_CHUCK_TOM_20160105.txt
M_V_JONES_OUT_20180105.txt
M_V_JONES_OUT_20170105.txt
M_V_JONES_OUT_20160105.txt
```

EDIT: `JER` was corrected to `_JER_`, as is the requirement

Comment: check this answer it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6863551/2913267

Comment: Escape `(`, `|` and `)` with a backslash.

Comment: @Cyrus thanks. I didn't have to include the brackets but escaping the | worked.

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop with `find` to this:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do 
   //things get done here
   echo "$file"
done < <(find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*($PATTERN).*" -print0)
```

- This script uses `gnu find`'s extended regex feature with `-regextype` option.
- We are also using bash's process substitution

Finally call your code as:

```
bash packageScript.sh -p 'TOM|JER'
```

Comment: I found a simpler solution (indicated the below) Thanks

Comment: ok just keep in mind that it will break for filename that may contain whitespace or glob characters.

Answer (score 0):

I escaped the `|` and that seems to have done the trick. Final command: 
`".*TOM.*\|.*_JER_.*"`