# Combine replacement of strings in pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following form:

```
df
Text

Apple
Banana
Ananas
...
```

And I want to replace several strings, but some of them will have the same ouptut afterwards. So right now I am using:

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace('Apple', 'Germany', regex=True)
df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace('Banana', 'South America', regex=True)
df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace('Ananas', 'South America', regex=True)
```

which leads to the desired outcome:

```
df
Text

Germany
South America
South America
...
```

But the command lines are getting some kind of messy, is there a smarter way to do it? Something like: `df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace('Ananas' or 'Banana', 'South America', regex=True)`

If I try, this logic: [Regex match one of two words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863518/regex-match-one-of-two-words)

`df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace(/^(Ananas|Banana)$/', 'South America', regex=True)` nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using one-liner with dictionary:

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace({'Apple': 'Germany', 'Banana': 'South America', 'Ananas': 'South America'}, regex=True)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
            Text
0        Germany
1  South America
2  South America
```

Comment: thx for the solution, the ohter logic from the related thread does not work for me, this one is working and skips some lines