# trying to use two different text to locate the same element using .withText for different environment

Tags: regex, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is this the correct way to find the element using two different texts, since that element has two different texts for two different environments.

.find(`div`).withText(`/text1 || text2/`)

Answer (score 1):

The way to use regular expressions is valid. However, the regular expression is not correct. It should be the following:

`.withText(/text1|text2/)`

See also: [Regex match one of two words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863518/regex-match-one-of-two-words)