# Discord.js check for multiple words in a one message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot answer with a one word to multiple variants of message:

```js
const bomba = new Discord.Client();
    
const a = "bomba" || "bomb" || "bob";
const b = "hey" || "sup" || "hello" || "hi";

bomba.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author == bomba.user) return;
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === a + b) {
        bomba.channels.cache.get(`${message.channel.id}`).send("Hi!");
    };
});
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Regex and the [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function to check the content of the message against several words. Take a look at the code below and give it a try:

```js
const bomba = new Discord.Client();
    
const clientNames = ["bomba", "bomb", "bob"].join('|');
const greetings = ["hey", "sup", "hello", "hi"].join('|');

const regex = new RegExp(`^(${clientNames})\\s(${greetings})$`, 'gi');

bomba.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author == bomba.user) return;
    if (message.content.match(regex)) {
        bomba.channels.cache.get(`${message.channel.id}`).send("Hi!");
    }
});
```

For more information about the regex, take a look at [this stackoverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863518/regex-match-one-of-two-words)

Comment: It works just like I wanted, but there's one problem: https://imgur.com/qCf5OAY
It doesn't reply when sees any other symbols or words beetween or with necessary words

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
if (["bomba", "bomb", "bob"].includes(message.content.toLowerCase())) {
    message.channel.send("Hi!");
};
```

---

Note that it would be better to compare the users by their `User.id` property, rather than checking if they refer to the same instance like you do in your code.

```js
if (message.author.id == bomba.user.id) return;
```

From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) about the `==` operator:

> If the operands are both objects, return true only if both operands reference the same object.