# Correct syntax to check multiple strings while user agent check

Tags: php

Is my syntax for checking multiple strings (existing of one of both strings) in a user agent correct?

I mean the part `'google|lighthouse'`. If not, what should be the correct kind of writing?

```
<?php if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'google|lighthouse') === false): ?>
// code
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It's wrong, unless you want to find actual string `google|lighthouse`. Use RegEx or separate `stripos`

Comment: @Justinas   I want to find one of both. According to this answer it should be correct - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6863551/1992004

Comment: That answer is using RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regular expression for that, otherwise you are just looking for literal sequence of `google|lighthouse`:

```php
<?php if (preg_match('/google|lighthouse/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? '') !== 1): ?>
// code
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not doing what you want to do. you are search for string 'google|lighthouse' inside the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], I guess you want something like

```
<?php if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'google') === false) || (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'lighthouse') === false): ?>
// code
<?php endif; ?>
```